# jackson fasterxml add namespaces to root element

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jackson, fasterxml

If I have the class `A.java`:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "A")
public class A {

}
```

The output that gets produced is:

```
 <A
    xmlns="">
```

I want to add a few more namespaces to the output, i.e. 
`xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com example.xsd"`

How do I configure `A.java` to contain more custom namespaces like these?

Comment: All namespaces needed for `A` should automatically be added by Jackson. Do you want to add some "useless" namespaces declarations ?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the question. I need to add some "useless" namespaces to the root element

Comment: @Hooli, have you considered using jaxb

Answer (score 3):

Since xsi:schemaLocation is an attribute, you can add it like that:

```
public class A implements Serializable {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "xsi:schemaLocation")
    private String schemaLocation = "urn:path:to.your.schema";
```

It did the job for me.